# Google Machine Learning Kit, Recognize Text in Images with ML Kit on Android error

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-mlkit

I tried to install "Recognize Text in Images with ML Kit on Android" then I'm running this app, I got this error:

> com.google.firebase.codelab.mlkit W/System.err:
>   com.google.firebase.ml.common.FirebaseMLException: Waiting for the
>   text recognition model to be downloaded

I waited for 4 or 5 hours with no response.

It showed up on this line:
[image: error]

To reproduce:

Follow the [Recognize Text in Images Codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/mlkit-android/#0) or [run the sample app code](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/tree/master/mlkit) and clear your app's cache.

Comment: what device are you using?

Comment: i'm using Samsung galaxy j3 (2016)

Comment: I had the same problem, I hope it works for you, too: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50334239/1934673

Comment: thanks. it worked successfull. ^^

Answer (score 2):

This can happen if the storage on the device is not sufficient. Can you try clearing the data for Google Play Services from the device?

Post development, to avoid this problem in production, you can use this tag in your manifest:

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.firebase.ml.vision.DEPENDENCIES"
    android:value="text" />
```

This will pre-download the recognition model upon app installation from Play Store.